# Show custom message inside react data grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I want to show message inside react-data-grid when no data to be found for render. I do not find any props to support that feature. There are method which can be used to render custom HTML for row and column but I want to show message in absolute centre of data-table. Any way to do this.

```
<ReactDataGrid
   rowHeight={50}
   columns={this.columns}
   rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
   rowsCount={rows.length}
/>
```

Comment: You could just have `ReactDataGrid` render in a `div`. Then, check if your data is available, if it is not, then render your centered content within the div, if it is, render this data grid.